# Javascript - Remove an entire div if it has an image in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a few divs like below, is it possible to remove or hide the divs that have images in them (I don't want to use something like nth-child in case another image is added in the future)

```
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div><img src="Image.jpg"</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's quite simple. What research have you done? What have you found in [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function() {       // for each div
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.find('img').length)  // if the div has images as descendants
    $this.remove();             // remove it
});
```

**Note:** If you're looking for `div`s that has images as direct children then replace `.find` with `.children`.

Comment: It's even simpler than that. :-)

Comment: Somebody just downvoted me and took it back. I didn't downvote you by the way, I upvoted!

Comment: It's not important. Frankly, none of us should have answered this question. I wasn't going to, but I saw an incorrect answer (now fixed) and an overly-complicated answer and couldn't restrain myself. :-)

Comment: `$("div:has(img)").remove()`

Comment: Even if handling descendants rather than just children, it really can be much simpler than this.

Comment: @Scott: Yeah, I stay away from jQuery's pseudo-selectors when I can. `:has` has a particularly fraught history wrt bugs and performance issues, though hopefully they've been resolved (last I checked was at least three years ago).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah true, I'm not sure what the internal workings of `:has` are, I just thought it was a cool one-line solution. According to the [jQuery site](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), using `.has()` is better than `:has`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the great things about jQuery is it's *set-based*. So: You find the set of `img`s directly contained by `divs` via [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) with a child combinator selector `div > img`, then find each of those `img`'s parent via [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), and remove them via [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$("div > img").parent().remove();
```

Example (with two divs with `img`s, just to demonstrate that the above doesn't just handle a single one):

```js
$("div > img").parent().remove();
```

```html
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div><img src="Image.jpg"></div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div><img src="Image.jpg"></div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to handle the `img` being *anywhere* within the `div`, not just as a child, just use a `div img` selector and [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$("div img").closest("div").remove();
```

Example:

```js
$("div img").closest("div").remove();
```

```html
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<!-- Note the added span to demonstrate finding a non-child img -->
<div><span><img src="Image.jpg"></span></div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<div><span><img src="Image.jpg"></span></div>
<div>Test 1</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was about to add that as second approach after I added the **note** to my answer!